# How do I convert NCIC code value to DCCIS code value for vehicle make?

Tags: xml, xslt

The business analyst told business rule for this has changed. Now they want me to first check (count) to see if there are more than one NcicCode (in the VehicleMakeMapping lookup document) matching MncisCode(in the input document). If there are more than one NcicCode in the VehicleMakeMapping lookup document, then just use the first NcicCode as the output. Also check if there is exact match (1 to 1) and use the NcicCode  where there is exact match. Otherwise, if there is no matching NcicCode  to the MncisCode then do not display anything (do nothing).

The new XML file I am now using looks like this:

```
    <VehicleMakeMapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>AUHE</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>AUST</MncisCode>
        <Description>Austin-Healy</Description>
    </Mapping>
<Mapping>
    <NcicCode>JEEP</NcicCode>
    <MncisCode>JEEP</MncisCode>
    <Description>Jeep (for model years 1989 throughresent)</Description>
</Mapping>
<Mapping>
    <NcicCode>JEP</NcicCode>
    <MncisCode>JEEP</MncisCode>
    <Description>Jeep (for model years prior to 1970)</Description>
</Mapping>  
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>AUPR</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>AUST</MncisCode>
        <Description>Austin Products, Inc.Subsidiary Austin Industries, Inc.</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>CHRS</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>CHRY</MncisCode>
        <Description>Chrysler Boat Co.</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>CHRY</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>CHRY</MncisCode>
        <Description>Chrysler</Description>
    </Mapping>
</VehicleMakeMapping>
```

These shows for example NCIC code MRCU has to be converted into DCCIS code MERC etc.

**Xml doc**

```
 <Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="IXML Case Notification Test" MessageID="67078058" xmlns="">
<Case InternalID="1616807927" ID="11747370" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <Charge ID="10547226" PartyID="16580814" CurrSentenceID="155092098" InternalChargeID="1616447618" InternalPartyID="1614482843" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
        <ChargeOffenseDate>03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleLicensePlateState>DC</VehicleLicensePlateState>
            <VehicleLicensePlateNumber>050KTU</VehicleLicensePlateNumber>
            <VehicleType Word="PASSVEH">Jeep (for model years prior to 1970)</VehicleType>
            <VehicleMake Word="JEEP">Austin-Healy</VehicleMake>
            <CommercialVehicleFlag>false</CommercialVehicleFlag>
            <HazardousVehicleFlag>false</HazardousVehicleFlag>
            <VehicleInactive>false</VehicleInactive>
        </Vehicle>
    </Charge>
</Case>
```

**xslt**

```
<xsl:template name="ChargeDetails">
    <ext:Vehicle>
        <nc:ItemStyleText>
            <xsl:value-of select="Vehicle/VehicleType"/>
        </nc:ItemStyleText>
        <nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/Charge/Vehicle/CommercialVehicleFlag"/>
        </nc:VehicleCMVIndicator>
        <j:VehicleMakeCode>
            <xsl:variable name="vVehicleMake">
        <xsl:value-of select="Vehicle/VehicleMake/@Word"/>                     </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vVehicleMakeCode" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\CourtXML\ConfigFiles\VehicleMakeMapping.xml'))/VehicleMakeMapping/Mapping[MncisCode=$vVehicleMake]/MncisCode"/>           <xsl:value-of select="$vVehicleMakeCode"/>              
        </j:VehicleMakeCode>
    </ext:Vehicle>
```

Comment: Is your external document with the codes in just a text file, or actually an XML file? If you are using XSLT 1.0, it really needs to be an XML file. Thanks!

Comment: It is a xml file.. I have added it to the question. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: "*These shows for example NCIC code MRCU has to be converted into DCCIS code MERC etc.*" I don't see anything like that in the XML file you have added. In any case, doing a lookup from an external XML file is very easy in XSLT 2.0, using a **key**.

Comment: I did not add the entire xml document because it is long with about 400 lines of code. What I added was just a sample.

Comment: Those acronyms mean absolutely nothing to most of us. Why don't you explain which values in the external XML map to values in the input XML? A desired output example would also be extremely helpful. (The easier you make it for us the more likely you'll get a prompt and helpful answer.)

Comment: Hello Daniel, the values I need to get from eternal XML is **Text**. `<EnumerationValue code="ACUR"><Text>Acura</Text> </EnumerationValue>`. In my XSL this is  `<j:VehicleMakeCode>
<xsl:variable name="vVehicleMake"><xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/Charge/Vehicle/VehicleMake/@Word"/>
</xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="values" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\CourtXML\SimpleTypes\VehicleTypeType.xml'))/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code=$vVehicleMake]/Text"/><xsl:value-of select="$values/Text"/>
</j:VehicleMakeCode>`

Comment: **1.** Please don't post code in comments. -- **2.** In your new example, there are **two** `Mapping` records matching `MncisCode` = "AUST". Why would the result be "AUHE" and not "AUPR" or "AUHE AUPR"?

Comment: I was able to figure this one out. I will post my solution code for others to see incase it helps someone in the future. Thanks guys for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there are more than one NcicCode in the VehicleMakeMapping lookup
>   document, then just use the first NcicCode as the output.

To simplify the question, let us have:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleMake Word="ABC">not important</VehicleMake>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleMake Word="XYZ">not important</VehicleMake>
    </Vehicle>
</root>
```

**VehicleMakeMapping.xml**

```
<VehicleMakeMapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>ABCA</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>ABC</MncisCode>
        <Description>abc</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>ABCB</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>ABC</MncisCode>
        <Description>abc abc</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>ABCC</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>ABC</MncisCode>
        <Description>abc abc abc</Description>
    </Mapping>  
</VehicleMakeMapping>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="map-doc" select="'path/to/VehicleMakeMapping.xml'"/>

<xsl:key name="mapping" match="Mapping" use="MncisCode" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Vehicle"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Vehicle">
    <Vehicle>
        <VehicleMakeCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('mapping', VehicleMake/@Word, document($map-doc))[1]/NcicCode"/>                     
        </VehicleMakeCode>
    </Vehicle>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Vehicle>
      <VehicleMakeCode>ABCA</VehicleMakeCode>
   </Vehicle>
   <Vehicle>
      <VehicleMakeCode/>
   </Vehicle>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for my question.

```
<j:VehicleMakeCode>
            <xsl:variable name="vVehicleMake">
                <xsl:value-of select="../Vehicle/VehicleMake/@Word"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="vVehicleMakeCode" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\VehicleMakeMapping.xml'))/VehicleMakeMapping/Mapping[MncisCode=$vVehicleMake]/NcicCode"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vVehicleMakeCode"/>
        </j:VehicleMakeCode>
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, out of context and - most importantly - does not return the specified result. If you do manage to match "AUST" with the external document, you will receive a result of `<j:VehicleMakeCode>AUHE AUPR</j:VehicleMakeCode>` (when using XSLT 2.0 as stated).

Comment: When I change the xml code for the VehicleMake to AUST, my result is    `<j:VehicleMakeCode>AUHE</j:VehicleMakeCode>`

Comment: Then you're not using XSLT 2.0. And the reason you're getting AUHE and not AUPR is only because AUHE happens to be first. If they change the order of your lookup document, your result will change too.

Comment: I see what you mean. What would you suggest changing in my xslt code?

Comment: The problem is not (yet) with the XSLT code. First, we need to know the business rules, i.e. which result to pick.

Comment: The business rule is that when the xml has a VehicleMakeCode that does not match the Ncic VehicleMakeCode, then display the Ncic code. When they both match just display the xml VehicleMakeCode code. Does that help?

Comment: You need another business rule that says: "When a Charge has a VehicleMakeCode that matches the MncisCode of two (or more) Mapping entries, each with a different NcicCode, pick the NcicCode that ... ???".

Comment: Oh I see. We go by description. The xml document has  <VehicleType Word="PASSVEH">Passanger Vehicle</VehicleType> which is the description of the vehicle. In the xslt this is <nc:ItemStyleText></nc:ItemStyleText>

Comment: But there is no corresponding "Passenger Vehicle" in the lookup document. Perhaps you need to match **both** VehicleMake/@Word and VehicleMake (i.e. "AUST" & "Austin-Healy")?

Comment: I agree. I will be working on this tomorrow. I will post here what happens. As always I am happy that everybody here is simply awesome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77626/discussion-between-angela-and-michael-hor257k).