# How do I check for either Canadian or US state codes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to display VehicleLicensePlateState code from XML document depending on whether or not is Canadian state code (e.g AB, BC, etc) or the US state code (WI, IL, etc).

First I need to check if either Canadian or US VehicleLicensePlateState code is found in the XML document.

If neither is found, I want to display JurisdictionText (in XML document the path is /Integration/Citation/Agency/@Word)

My IXML document can only have one VehicleLicensePlateState code at a time either US or Canadian but not both.

In order to check the Canadian VehicleLicensePlateState codes, there is a lookup .xsd document.

There is also a .xsd document with US VehicleLicensePlateState codes.  I have posted abbreviated code for each.

Based on my current XML document, output should look like this

```
<nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
    <nc:JurisdictionUSPostalServiceCode>QC</nc:JurisdictionUSPostalServiceCode>
</nc:IdentificationJurisdiction>
```

**XML code**

```
 <Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="IXML Case Notification Test" MessageID="67079943" xmlns="">
    <Case InternalID="876" ID="457" Op="A" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <Charge Op="A" ID="10906070" PartyID="16770190" InternalChargeID="1616713734" InternalPartyID="1614673227" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
            <Vehicle>
                <VehicleLicensePlateState>QC</VehicleLicensePlateState>
            </Vehicle>
        </Charge>
    </Case>
    <Citation Op="A" ID="5385325" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <Agency Op="A" Word="DCCON00E1"></Agency>
    </Citation>
</Integration>
```

**XSL code**

```
<nc:IdentificationJurisdiction> 
<nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="../Vehicle/VehicleLicensePlateState"/>
</nc:JurisdictionCanadianProvinceCode>
<nc:JurisdictionText>
    <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Citation/Agency/@Word"/>
</nc:JurisdictionText>
<nc:JurisdictionUSPostalServiceCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="../Vehicle/VehicleLicensePlateState"/>
</nc:JurisdictionUSPostalServiceCode>
```

**Canadian VehicleLicensePlateState codes document**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:structures="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:appinfo="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/" xmlns:can="http://release.niem.gov/niem/codes/canada_post/3.0/" xmlns:ct="http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/codes/canada_post/3.0/" version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/ ../../../appinfo/3.0/appinfo.xsd http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/ ../../../conformanceTargets/3.0/conformanceTargets.xsd" ct:conformanceTargets="http://reference.niem.gov/niem/specification/naming-and-design-rules/3.0/#ReferenceSchemaDocument">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Province codes for Canada</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:import namespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" schemaLocation="../../../structures/3.0/structures.xsd"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="CanadianProvinceCodeSimpleType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A data type for provinces in Canada.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="MB">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Manitoba</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="QC">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Qu&#xe9;bec</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="CanadianProvinceCodeType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A data type for provinces in Canada.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="can:CanadianProvinceCodeSimpleType">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="structures:SimpleObjectAttributeGroup"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**US VehicleLicensePlateState codes document**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:structures="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:appinfo="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/" xmlns:usps-3.0.1="http://publication.niem.gov/niem/codes/usps_states/3.0/1/" xmlns:ct="http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://publication.niem.gov/niem/codes/usps_states/3.0/1/" version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/ ../../../../appinfo/3.0/appinfo.xsd http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/ ../../../../conformanceTargets/3.0/conformanceTargets.xsd" ct:conformanceTargets="http://reference.niem.gov/niem/specification/naming-and-design-rules/3.0/#ReferenceSchemaDocument">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>U.S. Postal Service Supplement</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:import namespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" schemaLocation="../../../../structures/3.0/structures.xsd"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="USStateCodeSimpleType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A data type for states.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="AA">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Armed Forces Americas (except Canada)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="HI">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>HAWAII</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="IL">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>ILLINOIS</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="USStateCodeType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A data type for states.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="usps-3.0.1:USStateCodeSimpleType">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="structures:SimpleObjectAttributeGroup"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Instead of using two XSD documents, why don't you make it easy for yourself and everyone else and produce a single combined XML to be used as the source for the lookup? -- In any case, the solution here is to use a **key** - same as in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30127613/3016153).

Comment: I am not sure how to combine the 2 lookup documents together. They are not also not similar.

Comment: See, that's a much more interesting question. Try applying [this stylesheet](http://pastebin.com/AXj5Z5Ek) to both of them, then just copy and paste to combine them.