# How do I display NcicCode matching VehicleMake (MncisCode)?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml document with `<VehicleMake Word="MERC">Mercury</VehicleMake>`element. I would like to match it with the `<NcicCode>MERC</NcicCode>` code.
My output is only displaying the first `<NcicCode>` that matches `<MncisCode>`. The `<MncisCode>` in the referring document is the same as `<VehicleMakeCode>` code in my xml document.

**Current output**

`<ext:Vehicle>
    <j:VehicleMakeCode>MERB</j:VehicleMakeCode>
</ext:Vehicle>`

**Desired output should be NcicCode = MncisCode**

`<ext:Vehicle>
    <j:VehicleMakeCode>MERC</j:VehicleMakeCode>
</ext:Vehicle>`

**My sample xml document**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67092480" xmlns="">
    <Case Op="E" InternalID="1617090885" ID="12126951" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <Charge ID="10906495" PartyID="1466236" InternalChargeID="1616714163" InternalPartyID="704451330" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
            <ChargeOffenseDate>06/05/2015</ChargeOffenseDate>
            <Vehicle>
                <VehicleMake Word="MERC">Mercury</VehicleMake>
            </Vehicle>
        </Charge>
    </Case>
    <Citation ID="5385632" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <CitationNumber>TLA060515C</CitationNumber>
        <TicketDate>06/05/2015</TicketDate>
        <Vehicle>
            <VehicleMake Word="MERC">Mercury</VehicleMake>
        </Vehicle>
    </Citation>
</Integration>
```

**My sample referring xml document**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VehicleMakeMapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>MERB</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>MERC</MncisCode>
        <Description>Mercury Boat Co.</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>MERC</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>MERC</MncisCode>
        <Description>Mercury</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>MERH</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>MERC</MncisCode>
        <Description>Mercury Coach Corp.</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>MERR</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>MERC</MncisCode>
        <Description>Mercury Trailer Industries</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>METE</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>MERC</MncisCode>
        <Description>Meteor (Canadian Mercury)</Description>
    </Mapping>
    <Mapping>
        <NcicCode>MRCU</NcicCode>
        <MncisCode>MERC</MncisCode>
        <Description>Mercury (See Mercury Marine)</Description>
    </Mapping>
</VehicleMakeMapping>
```

**My sample xslt code**

```
<j:VehicleMakeCode>
        <xsl:variable name="vVehicleMakeCode" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\VehicleMakeMapping.xml'))/VehicleMakeMapping/Mapping[MncisCode=$vVehicleMake]/NcicCode"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vVehicleMakeCode"/>
</j:VehicleMakeCode>
```

Comment: In your sample document, all the `Mapping` elements have the same `MncisCode`, so how will it know which one to match? Thanks!

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127613/how-do-i-convert-ncic-code-value-to-dccis-code-value-for-vehicle-make ?

Comment: Business analyst said (to use `VehicleMake` description also) they want.. VehicleMake value returned will be based on MNCIS codes.  The NCIC codes do not have a one to on match with the Vehicle Make codes used in MNCIS. When the results in the XML include VehicleMake, convert the value from the MNCIS value to the matching NCIC value in the VehicleMake Mapping document.  If more than one NCIC code is found for the MNCIS code look for an exact match and populate, else skip this element.   
If no NCIC code is found for the MNCIS code skip populating the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `Description` nodes comparison also in your predicate. I am guessing something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="vVehicleMakeCode" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\VehicleMakeMapping.xml'))/VehicleMakeMapping/Mapping[MncisCode=$vVehicleMake and Description=$vVehicleMakeContent]/NcicCode"/>
```

you have to map `$vVehicleMakeContent` to the contents of the target node.

**EDIT**

Try this one instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="vVehicleMakeCode" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\VehicleMakeMapping.xml'))/VehicleMakeMapping/Mapping[MncisCode=$vVehicleMake and MncisCode=NcicCode]/NcicCode"/>
```

Comment: The business people told me to find for exact match between `/Integration/Case/Charge/Vehicle/VehicleMake/@Word` code and `NcicCode`. If no match is found, then I need to skip it i.e do not display it. So in my case based on the xml document I have, the output should be like this `<ext:Vehicle>
    <j:VehicleMakeCode>MERC</j:VehicleMakeCode>
</ext:Vehicle>` because `MERC` matches both `NcicCode` and `MncisCode`

Comment: Joel, business analyst asked me not to use description when finding exact match between `NcicCode` and `MncisCode`. So I am not sure what to change on my xsl to loop through the `Mapping` looking for exact match between `NcicCode` and `MncisCode` The xml document  has `/Integration/Case/Charge/Vehicle/VehicleMake/@Word` the `@Word` is the `MncisCode` which I need to match with the `NcicCode` in the `Mapping` document. If there is not an exact match between `NcicCode` and `MncisCode` then I need not display the code. How do I do this?